# Couldn't execute cucumber script using tags from command line

Tags: selenium, maven, command-line, tags, cucumber

I have created a small project to execute cucumber test using command line, when I specify my runner class path in maven surefire plugin I can able to execute my cucumber test using command line (here all the scenarios are getting picked up), but when I comment and I try to run using tag option I'm getting build successfully but nothing gets executed. command used mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Flipkart"

```
<plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        <!--        <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                    <includes>
                        <exclude>**/*TestRunner.java</exclude>
                    </includes>
                    
                </configuration>-->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>

package Runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features= {"src/test/resources/Features"},
        glue= {"stepDefinition"})
//      tags="@Flipkart",
        
public class MyTestRunner {

}

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< WebdriverTest:WebdriverTest >---------------------
[INFO] Building WebdriverTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/cucumber/messages/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/cucumber/messages/maven-metadata.xml (1.9 kB at 771 B/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ WebdriverTest ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Parallel\WebdriverTest\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ WebdriverTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ WebdriverTest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ WebdriverTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ WebdriverTest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Parallel\WebdriverTest\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test) @ WebdriverTest ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ WebdriverTest ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Parallel\WebdriverTest\target\WebdriverTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ WebdriverTest ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Parallel\WebdriverTest\target\WebdriverTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\user_name\.m2\repository\WebdriverTest\WebdriverTest\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WebdriverTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Parallel\WebdriverTest\pom.xml to C:\Users\user_name\.m2\repository\WebdriverTest\WebdriverTest\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WebdriverTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.196 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-19T11:56:06+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

ANSWER:
for me -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Flipkart" not working with tags (Don't know why it is not working if someone knows the answer please share)

-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Flipkart" working without doing any changes in my Pom

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you tag scenarios in feature file?

Comment: the surefire plugin spawn a new process to run the tests. There is an "argLine" property you can use to pass variables to that process: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine - so maybee mvn test -DargLine='-Dcucumber.options="--tags @Flipkart"' will work. Or you could create a maven profile to add some comfort.

Comment: I tried the above command still the test didn't launched, only build is getting success. I don't know about maven profile, could you please provide some details on it. @wemu

Comment: I'll try adding the profile example later, meanwhile: did you run the command with the above pom? because your test does not match the default include patterns: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes

Comment: btw where do you have the cucumber.options from? the https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/ does not mention it

Answer (score 0):

SO. I think the option you are using does not exist. But there is a "cucumber.filter.tags" option. To create a maven profile that just enables tests with one specific tag or filter.

The example pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

        <default.surefire.argline></default.surefire.argline>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*TestRunner*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <argLine>${default.surefire.argline}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>cucumber-flipkart</id>
            <properties>
                <default.surefire.argline>-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Flipkart"</default.surefire.argline>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

to activate a profile: `mvn test -Pcucumber-flipkart`

a feature file might look like:

```
@Flipkart
Feature: Flipper swims north.

  Background: Fish needs cold water

    Scenario: Flipper goes swimming
      Given Flipper is hungry
      When he decides to go eating
      Then Flipper swims north.
```

The Test Runner and step definitions are in the same package, the feature files are in the corresponding folder in the resources. So the runner does not need that much config:

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-report.html"})
public class MyTestRunner {
}
```

This should do :)